# Manually add translations for some words while using google translate

Tags: php, google-translate

I am using google translate to translate my website from english to arabic. But there are few words which are showing wrong translations.
Is there any way to manually define translations for some strings?

Comment: Am afraid that your question is not clear enough. you are manually translating your website, no ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui No I am using google translate to translate my website from english to arabic. But there are a few words for which the translations seems to be not very accurate. Is there any way by which i can manually add translations for those particular words?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array key, values English => Arabic for wrong translated words. Before the google translation function runs, check this array you created if the word you wanna translate is inside this array then just return the value from the array if this word doesn't exist inside the array return the value from google translate.

**Edit**

There are many ways to solve this problem. For example, you can create a table in the database with key and value structure. The key field is English words and the value field is Arabic translation. You can create a global helper function to use in your view. When you query the database for better performance you can store values in-memory cache systems such as Redis.

```
public function translate($key)
{
    $cacheKey = 'Translations.' . $key;
    if ($cacheItem = (Redis::get($key) === null)) {
        $query = 'select value from translations where key = :key';
        $result = $this->GetConnection()->prepare($query)->execute([
            ':key' => $key,
        ]);

        if (!$result) {
            return null;
        }

        Redis::set($cacheKey, $result);
    }

    return $cacheItem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wayout. But I am not very clear about how i can implement it. Can you please help with a code snippet?